# adding removing an ng-class on a ng-click function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I have created a an `ng-click`function which is doing the basics i need, add an active state class [click here](http://jsbin.com/fecajagi/1/edit). I seem to be have an issue, removing the active class when i want to click out of the active.

```
 <div ng-click="showTooltip(activeTooltip)" ng-class="{ active: activeTooltip == active }">Tooltip!</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('IndexController', function($scope) {

 $scope.activeTooltip = 'Adam';
 $scope.active = '';

 $scope.showTooltip = function(active) {

$scope.active = active;

};
```

});

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `$scope.active` is a string, so doing `$scope.active = !$scope.activeq` doesn't make much sense. Why don't you post all relevant code (correctly formatted), so we can reproduce it ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem if you click on the link i provided you'll see the relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have implemented it (which doesn't make much sense btw), you need to register a listener for the `click` event on the window object (and because we are in Angular we should use the `$window` service).

Every time the window object receives the click event it should reset `$scope.active` to `''`.
Furthermore, when calling `$scope.showTooltip()`, we need to stop further propagation of the `click` event, so it doesn't reach the window object if it is captured by the `<div>` first.

---

Your controller should be changed like this:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.activeTooltip = 'Adam';
    $scope.active = '';

    $scope.showTooltip = function (active, evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();   // Don't let it reach $window
        $scope.active = active;    
    };

    $window.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        $scope.$apply($scope.showTooltip.bind($scope, '', evt));
    });
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsbin.com/kedifere/1/edit)**.

---

It turned out I didn't get the actual requiements, which is that the tooltip class should be toggled (added/removed) each time the user clicks on the div. So, there is no need for an event-listener on the `window` and the code should be modified like this:

```
app.controller('IndexController', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.activeTooltip = 'Adam';
    $scope.active = '';

    $scope.showTooltip = function (active) {
        $scope.active = ($scope.active === active) ? '' : active;
    };
});

<div ng-class="{active:activeTooltip===active}"
     ng-click="showTooltip(activeTooltip)">
    Tooltip!
</div>
```

See, also, this other **[short demo](http://jsbin.com/kedifere/2/edit)**.

Comment: However is there anyway this can me changed to deactive the the class when you click on the element toolTip rather outside of the div?

Comment: Where is the tooltip ?

Comment: BTW, it is nt very nice to "unaccept" an answer that does solve the original problem (as stated in your question), just because you came up with additional requirements :)

Comment: The word "tooltip" at present, you have to click outside of the area in order to remove the class. This where you have applied "$window.addEventListener" Also why do you have an eventlistner in your function, it defeats the purpose of "ng-click" :)

Comment: The `ngClick` is for DOM elements. The `window` object is not a DOM element, so there is no way to use `ngClick` with the `window` object. So, you want to activate/deactivate the tooltip when you click on the div ? (e.g. click -> activate, click again -> deactivate etc)

Comment: yes, that's correct, i want to active/deactivate the tooltip when you click on the div